# How do I block a specific word from being entered in my HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to set up a simple account creation form for a game. I'm going to post my HTML and PHP that is being used below.

What I want to do is block the following words from being entered into a characters name:

```
Mod, Owner, Mawd, M0d, 0wner
```

Also, I need to block special characters such as these:

```
!@#$%^&*()_+|\`~
```

Once those get blocked, my form will be 100% finished, unless I decide to change the template for it.

Here is the PHP code that checks the text entered into the form.

```
<?php //data.php
require_once 'login.php';

// Get values from form
$NAME        = $_POST['char_name'];
$PASS        = $_POST['char_pass']; 
$FORUM       = $_POST['forum_name'];
$TESTER      ="0";
$BANNED      ="0";
$RANK        ="1";

// Check if form is empty
if(trim($NAME) == '' || trim($PASS) == '' || trim($FORUM) == ''){
header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/notfilled.html');
}

// Check for duplicates
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='$NAME'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/characterexists.html');
}else{

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO accounts (username,password,forumname,tester,banned,rank)
VALUES ('$NAME','$PASS','$FORUM','$TESTER','$BANNED','$RANK')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
header('Location: http://runerecovery.us/ingame/registered.html');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
}
```

Comment: "Once those get blocked, my form will be 100% finished" i hope not, its completely open to exploitation

Comment: This is wide open to SQL injection. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/SQL_Injection

Comment: how can I change that?

Comment: Read the link. Google "mysql_query SQL injection"

Comment: I'm not sure "blocking" is a correct tag for this question. Check out http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059 for an explanation of PDO

Comment: Are you looking to block user names equal to those in your block list or containing those in your block list, e.g. would "UberMod" be blocked?

Comment: ALWAYS, I repeat, ALWAYS protect yourself from sql inection. Hackers won't seek out your trivial game, they have automated bots that will do that for them. You have user names and passwords stored in a database. I'm betting the passwords are not encrypted. So when a hacker gets a username/passowrd pair... many people will use that pair elsewhere, you have just compromised your users details.

Comment: @user3626726 StackOverflow isn't a learning resource, per-se. It is somewhwere to get help for a specific question you may have. Now you have provided a specfic question, that's a good start. The answers provided will help solve that question. What we can't do is teach you the basics. That's up to you. Get a book, I stated with: http://www.ebook3000.com/PHP-and-MySQL-Web-Development--4th-Edition_199055.html, do a course and Google PHP debugging

Answer (score 2):

You could the following code below. I would add it after you check if any of the fields are empty. The code below will work for all upper and lower cases.

```
$invalidCharacterNames = array('Mod', 'Owner', 'Mawd', 'M0d', '0wner');

foreach($invalidCharacterNames as $invalidCharacterName){
    if(strtolower($invalidCharacterName) == trim(strtolower($NAME))){
        //redirect to error page
        header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/invalid_character_name.html')
    }
}
```

Most importantly, your form is vulnerable to sql injection - read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Also, I suggest you use mysqli and prepared statements
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Update: use preg_match or strpos to check for the specific characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Just create an array containing a list of banned items—such as names—and then use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) to compare the value of `trim($NAME)` against it. I would recommend placing after the check to see if the form is empty like this:

```
// Check if form is empty
if(trim($NAME) == '' || trim($PASS) == '' || trim($FORUM) == ''){
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/notfilled.html');
}

// Set an array of banned names.
$banned_names = array('Mod', 'Owner', 'Mawd', 'M0d', '0wner');

// Check if the name is banned.
if(in_array(trim($NAME), $banned_names)) {
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/banned.html');
}
```

For these characters:

```
!@#$%^&*()_+|\`~
```

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) to see if those characters are in the name as well and act on them as well. I will see if I can put something together.

**EDIT:** Okay, I have a nice `preg_match` that will work well for the characters above:

```
preg_match("/(!|@|#|$|%|\^|\&|\(|\)| _|\+|\|\\|`|~)/is", trim($NAME));
```

Now create a conditional that can use that like so:

```
// Check if the name has banned characters.
if(preg_match("/(!|@|#|$|%|\^|\&|\(|\)| _|\+|\|\\|`|~)/is", trim($NAME))) {
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/banned.html');
}
```

And bring it all together like this:

```
// Check if form is empty
if(trim($NAME) == '' || trim($PASS) == '' || trim($FORUM) == ''){
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/notfilled.html');
}

// Check if the name has banned characters.
if(preg_match("/(!|@|#|$|%|\^|\&|\(|\)| _|\+|\|\\|`|~)/is", trim($NAME))) {
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/banned.html');
}

// Set an array of banned names.
$banned_names = array('Mod', 'Owner', 'Mawd', 'M0d', '0wner');

// Check if the name is banned.
if(in_array(trim($NAME), $banned_names)) {
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/banned.html');
}
```

Also, instead of `in_array` you could also use [`preg_grep`](https://www.php.net/preg_grep) to do a case insensitive match like so:

```
// Check if the name is banned.
if(preg_grep("/" . trim($NAME) . "/i" , $banned_names)) {
  header('Location: http://www.runerecovery.us/ingame/banned.html');
}
```

Comment: I add this code to my PHP and whenever I click my submit button it does nothing but get stuck at the  data.php page.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the above code. I add it into my PHP and it just skips right over it. I'm not understanding why this is happening. Would anyone be willing to contact me via Skype to possibly help? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was not begging. I'm looking at the advice here, I was wondering if someone could contact me via skype to teach me. Not fix the problem for me. I in no way want someone to do this for me. Just simply guide me to solving me. None of the stuff on here seems to be working for me. I don't know if its the placement of the code, or something completely different. It's hard for me to do PHP as I've never done it before.

Comment: I'd just do a simple alpa-numeric check [a-z][0-9]

Comment: @JakeGould you've got me there, haven't had enough coffe yet either.